# Installation of postresql on amazon linux server fails

Tags: postgresql, amazon-ec2

I try to install postgresql-server on amazone linux, but it fails:

```
[ec2-user@ip-xyz ~]$ sudo yum install postgresql-server
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main/latest                                         | 2.1 kB     00:00     
amzn-updates/latest                                      | 2.3 kB     00:00     
961 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package postgresql93-server.x86_64 0:9.3.12-1PGDG.rhel7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: postgresql93-server-9.3.12-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd-units for package: postgresql93-server-9.3.12-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: postgresql93-server-9.3.12-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: systemd-units
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

There seems to be an issue with unfulfilled requirements. 
How can I solve this: `Error: Package: postgresql93-server-9.3.12-1PGDG.rhel7.x86_64 (pgdg93)
           Requires: systemd-units`